# Installing SSRS on SQL Server 2012 SP3

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, installation

I'd like to add SSRS to a SQL Server 2012 SP3 installation. My question is, can I install this from the original SQL Server installation disk (i.e. no service pack), or must I find an SP3 version of SSRS?

Apologies if this is an odd question. Currently on a short-term contract and I'm trying to make sense of the various SQL-related ISOs and EXEs on the installation drives. I don't want to install SSRS from the original ISO file, to find that it doesn't work (or worse, somehow impacts the rest of the server).

Thanks.

Comment: Please give a try to install SSRS with original ISO - adding feature for report service. Then apply SP3 on the same feature you just installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install from the ISO and then patch SSRS to SP3.
Following CMD command can also be used to update during the install:

```
Setup.exe /Action=Install /UpdateEnabled=TRUE /UpdateSource="C:\SQLUpdates"
```

Source:
http://cecildt.blogspot.dk/2012/08/sql-server-2012-slipstream-updates-has.html